# How can I load an image(.png) from PersistantDataPath to a Texture2D in Unity3D?

Tags: android, image, unity-game-engine, io

I would like to share an image with the Soomla Profile plugin and that requires a texture2d. I capture a screen shot (`Application.CaptureScreenshot("Screenshot.png");`) before the game ends and than I want to share it. How can I turn a Png image to a Texture2D?

This is how I reach the image: `pathToScreeShot = Application.persistentDataPath + "/ScreenShotHiScore.png";`

*(And btw. I want to release the game for android phones.)*

Answer (score 1):

you can use following code to load image from persistant data path

```
    string imageString = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine( Application.persistentDataPath,"imagePath"));
    byte[] byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(imageString);
    Texture2D tex =new Texture2D(2,2);
    tex.LoadImage(byteArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/432655/loading-texture-file-from-pngjpg-file-on-disk.html) thread. The second answer should fit your needs.